# Using my own code in freelance projects

Tags: legal, code-reuse

I have been into freelance business for more than 2 years. While doing projects for other people, I've build a compilation of common tasks that I implement in projects and put them into code. It's kind of a library with some functions that I can reuse without having to rewrite the same thing dozen times. I'm talking about accessing Access databases, downloading information from FTP and similar stuff.

Is this acceptable from a legal point of view? What's the difference in reusing the old code and rewriting it from the scratch (using you own brain again, therefore the exact same logic)?

I do not hold any copyright to it, of course, and provide the source code for these classes to my clients.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, unless you have signed over copyright, you *are* the copyright holder (of course, this depends on what country you are in - the US and UK give the author automatic copyright).

In general, there is nothing wrong with this practice - just make sure when signing contracts that you are not giving away your rights to this code.

Comment: I second this. And nothing wrong with that at all. I think that most programmers develop their "me-framework" over time for sure. It is good practice too in my opinion as it allows you to refine your code over time and also become very fluent in it.